# Fan noise, too hot, lagging, Ubuntu 16.04 on laptop hp pavillion g6

Tags: 16.04, cpu, overheating, fan

The CPU is overused near at 100% with no reason and I've read that maybe is a graphics problem so below i have my specs if anybody could help.

Laptop specs:

- hp g6 pavillion
- cpu intel core i3-3110
- 2.4 4gb ram

`sudo lshw -c video` gives the following output:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series]
       κατασκευαστής: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       πληροφορίες διαύλου: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       πλάτος: 64 bits
       ρολόι: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       πόροι: irq:30 μνήμη:a0000000-afffffff μνήμη:c2000000-c201ffff ioport:4000(size=256) μνήμη:c2020000-c203ffff

  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       κατασκευαστής: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       πληροφορίες διαύλου: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       πλάτος: 64 bits
       ρολόι: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       πόροι: irq:29 μνήμη:c3000000-c33fffff μνήμη:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

Answer (score 0):

determine which process is using your cpu by running **top** or **ps aux** in your terminal(ctrl+alt+t)

post output here or try killing the process by running "**kill PID**" in the terminal. PID is the second column in "ps aux" first column in "top"